# VisualStudio WDK extension not installing

Tags: wdk

after i installed the WDK It auto installed the Visualstudio WDK extension, which is what i want
but It says this Instead

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Visualstudio.Validation, Version=17.6.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Then if i try and open C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Vsix\VS2022\10.0.22621.0\WDK.vsix it says

```
The Following files were specified on the command line:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Vsix\VS2022\10.0.22621.0\WDK.vsix

These files could not be found and will not be loaded
```

even though its definitely there